# Why is Visual Studio 2010 ultimate crashing a few seconds after opening?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crash

I disabled and uninstalled all the extensions and add-ons.

Everything was working fine up until I upgraded to NuGet 1.1.. then this started happening...

So I thought it was Nuget... I uninstalled Nuget (under admin rights)... restarted PC and VS and waited a few seconds then crash!

I have no idea how to investigate or debug this situation short of uninstalling all of Visual Studio and starting afresh.

Anyone know what to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run the following command line from the VS command line tools:

> devenv.exe /?

This will show different command that may help, especially :

> devenv.exe /safemode

does it works in safe mode ?

> devenv.exe /log

Produces a log files which can help isolating the problem

> devenv.exe /resetsettings
>
> devenv.exe /resetaddin
>
> devenv.exe /resetskippkgs

can help also

*[edit] devenv.exe /log added....*

Comment: please check my edit. Use the /log argument to produce a log file. The content of the log file may help

Comment: according [/log switch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms241272.aspx), the file is located here : `%APPDATA%\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\<version>\ActivityLog.xml.`

Comment: @Steve B what am I looking for in the ActivityLog?

Comment: @CVertex: obviously at anything that looks like anormal :) I don't know all the possible causes of problem. Try by searching "ERR" in the file, and start digging around to see if something is broken. If not, as TToni said, reinstall VS may be an option (but a long one)

Comment: Okay, I'll try reinstalling VS2010

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do a repair installation of Visual Studio. It's an option available from the Setup.

Comment: For me repair install broke a plenty of things -- to recover I had to remove then reinstall SP1 and all the hotfixes. I do mean remove, reapply left old versions of files.

Comment: Ouch. So I guess "repair" is not a viable option except when no updates have been applied so far (haha).