# All of a sudden can't open solution in VS2010 - why?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

So all of a sudden every time I open this one particular solution it crashes and gives me the following error. Anyone know what might be causing this? Here is the error I get:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: devenv.exe
  Application Version:  10.0.40219.1
  Application Timestamp:    4d5f2a73
  Fault Module Name:    KERNELBASE.dll
  Fault Module Version: 6.1.7601.18015
  Fault Module Timestamp:   50b83c8a
  Exception Code:   e0434352
  Exception Offset: 0000c41f
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    1033

Additional information about the problem:
  LCID: 1033

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

Comment: Try to follow these steps : http://stackoverflow.com/a/4990795/588868

Comment: Nope, that didn't fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found the answer accidentally by searching the MSDN forums:

**DELETE THE .SUO FILE**

This fixed it! Thanks everyone!

Comment: That will work most of the time. You should always make a backup of the file before deleting, because if solution is under source control you can make a lot more work for yourself. I would prefer to restore from sorce control or from a backup.

Comment: anyone know why this works? (it didn't seem like the file now is different from the file I used to have)

Comment: This is the file that stores the IDE state.  Keeps track of what windows were open and where they are located, stuff like that.  It isn't critical.  You'd typically suspect an add-in to corrupt it.

Answer (score 2):

This is a dublicate question ([Why is Visual Studio crashing after a few seconds [StackOverflow]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990760/why-is-visual-studio-2010-ultimate-crashing-a-few-seconds-after-opening/4990795#4990795), [Visual Studio crash [StackOverflow]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/9cytz106%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)).

**Possible Solutions**

- [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990760/why-is-visual-studio-2010-ultimate-crashing-a-few-seconds-after-opening/4990795#4990795)
- [StackExchange](http://fogbugz.stackexchange.com/questions/6506/visual-studio-add-in-causes-vs2010-to-crash-on-start-up)
- [MSDN Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/196ee627-b180-4e9c-a28e-81625d0c5cae/)

**Also see**

[/LCID (devenv.exe) [MSDN]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/9cytz106%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: None of these worked. It just happens when I open 1 solution. The rest of the solutions seem fine.